# tf.function slows TF training 10x

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, optimization

There are tons of questions regarding why tf.function slows down the self-defined model training step, and the usual answer is you cannot include plain python variables or python functions such as `for` in the code. However, I am still having quite a painful time figuring out why my code below runs 10x slower with tf.function compared to without it. I have been stuck with it for over a week. Please help. Thanks!

So I have defined a custom Tensorflow model called `combined_model`, which inputs one dataset and output two labels. I wrap the `train_step` function with `tf.function` as follows:

```
@tf.function
def train_step(x_batch_train, y_batch_train, domain_label):        
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        l_logits, d_logits = combined_model(x_batch_train, training=True)
        loss_value = get_loss(y_batch_train, l_logits, domain_label, d_logits)
                
    grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, combined_model.trainable_weights)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, combined_model.trainable_weights))
```

Then, I compile and fit the model using the following code:

```
def model_fit(training_dataset):   
    epochs = 30
    max_step = tf.constant(251, dtype=tf.int64)
    domain_label = tf.concat([tf.ones([BATCH_SIZE,1]),tf.zeros([BATCH_SIZE,1])], axis = 0)
    
    for epoch in tf.range(epochs):
        for step, (source, target) in training_dataset.enumerate(): 
            x, y, _ = source
            z = target 
            d = combine(x,z) # cancatenate x and z
            
            x_batch_train = d
            y_batch_train = y
            
            train_step(x_batch_train, y_batch_train, domain_label) 
            if tf.math.equal(step, max_step):
                break

model_fit(training_dataset)
```

I record time to run the `train_step` function in `model_fit` function and realized it's about 10x more with decoration from `tf.function`.
I checked all variable types, and they are all tf.Tensors(either sparseTensor or DenseTensor or EagerTensor). I also changed python function to tf ops as you can see in `model_fit`.

Still, none of the above solution worked. Any suggestions?

Comment: What kind of network are you using? Could you provide the loss function and if possible the model?

Comment: try to make [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so people here can help you better and faster